# AWS Elastic Beanstalk schedule deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to run few php scripts twice a day, and script execution won't last more than 60s per script.

AWS EB is working really fine to do the job, but I don't see any reason to pay for an EC2 instance running all day if I can pay half an hour a day.

Is there any solution to schedule application deployment, script execution and terminate application ?

Comment: Just a note, you can never pay just "half an hour a day". AWS charges for EC2 instances by the hour.

Comment: I meant "not pay a full day if I'm not using EC2 instance all day !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to pay for.  Elastic Beanstalk  provides deployment and management tools to run your application code, rather than just a plain instance.  How valuable is that to you?

If you can figure out your own deployment pipeline, you might look at setting up an Autoscaling group with [scheduled scaling](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/schedule_time.html) actions.

While Elastic Beanstalk environments can also do scheduled scaling actions, I believe it only does so with load-balanced environments, where you would have to pay for the load balancer (~$20/month).

Running a t2-micro instance in a single-instance EB environment without a load balancer is only ~$10/month.  You could spend even less on an annual basis with reserved instances.  If the alternative is spending time designing, configuring, deploying, and managing an alternate solution, you could do a lot worse.  I certainly recommend starting with EB.

Comment: I was looking for an AWS feature to easily schedule server up & down, or an external service. More than "designing, configuring, deploying, and managing" any solution.
I think I'll keep it up, even if I need it 1 hour twice a day :)

Answer (score 1):

If  you want to run scripts, I would look at the Lambda serverless model. You only pay for activity which means idle code won't cost you.